# anonymous function exercise in Wickham's Advanced R book

Tags: r

Below is a question from Wickham's Advanced R book which I can solve easily enough if I do it in three separate parts, but I was wondering if it can be done using a list of functions and list(s) of limits of integration in case the problem had many more than three functions to integrate.

(I am very much a newbie - struggling through the Coursera/Johns Hopkins R course, so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question)

QUESTION: Use `integrate()` and an anonymous function to find the area under the curve for the following functions. Use Wolfram Alpha to check your answers.

1. y = x ^ 2 - x, x in [0, 10]
2. y = sin(x) + cos(x), x in [-π, π]
3. y = exp(x) / x, x in [10, 20]

The following code works to solve parts 1-3 separately:

```
ans_1 <- integrate(function(x) x^2 -x, 0, 10  )
ans_2 <- integrate(function(x) sin(x) + cos(x), -pi, pi   )
ans_3 <- integrate(function(x) exp(x) / x, 10, 20 )
```

Many thanks in advance for any help :-<)

Comment: you could use mapply; in case the integrands have similar behaviour and equal integration limits you could also consider adaptIntegrate in the cubature package, which can work with vector-valued integrands.

Comment: it's entirely possible @TheloniusMick did `π <- pi` at some point previously.

Comment: Sorry you're right - when posting I stupidly cut and pasted the problem from the text and then recycled the symbol "π" but I actually used "pi" in my code.

Answer (score 2):

There definitely are many elegant ways but I can't think of one.

One straightforward approach

```
f1 <- c(f=function(x) x^2 -x,          l=0,   u=10)
f2 <- c(f=function(x) sin(x) + cos(x), l=-pi, u=pi)
f3 <- c(f=function(x) exp(x) / x,      l=10,  u=20)
funs <- list(f1,f2,f3)
lapply(funs, function(x)integrate(x[['f']], x[['l']], x[['u']]))

#[[1]]
#283.3333 with absolute error < 3.1e-12

#[[2]]
#2.615901e-16 with absolute error < 6.3e-14

#[[3]]
#25613160 with absolute error < 2.8e-07
```

and mapply suggested by @baptiste

```
functions <- list(function(x) x^2 -x, function(x) sin(x) + cos(x), function(x) exp(x) / x)
lower <- c(0, -pi, 20)
upper <- c(10, pi, 20)
mapply(integrate, functions, lower, upper)

#             [,1]        [,2]         [,3]      
#value        283.3333    2.615901e-16 0         
#abs.error    3.14928e-12 6.304916e-14 0         
#subdivisions 1           1            1         
#message      "OK"        "OK"         "OK"      
#call         Expression  Expression   Expression
```

Comment: I'm a fairly knowledgeable R user and that approach (constructing a list of lists) seems completely natural to me. I'm upvoting and think you should remove the "worst possible" label. Your data structure seems more "natural" than jlhoward's.

Comment: If you wanted to make it more self-documenting why not label your list items and access them by name: `integrate(x[['fun']], x[['ll']], x[['ul']])`

Comment: That I think is the wisdom of the knowledgeable user.

Comment: On the other note, building on this structure, I thought there was no obvious extentions to the other functionals such as `optimize`. Hence the sloppy "worst possible" label.

Comment: I don't understand. The only mismatch would be that optimize has different argument names. My suggestion (as was your original) was still using positional matching, so would have "worked" with simple change from `integrate` to `optimize`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems utterly pointless but since you asked, you can vectorize the integrate function wrt to the first three arguments, then pass a list of functions and limits.

```
v.int <- Vectorize(integrate,vectorize.args=c("f","lower","upper")) 
fns <- list(function(x) x^2-x, function(x) sin(x)+cos(x), function(x) exp(x)/x)
v.int(fns,lower=c(0,-pi,10),upper=c(10,pi,20))
#              [,1]        [,2]         [,3]        
# value        283.3333    2.615901e-16 25613160    
# abs.error    3.14928e-12 6.304916e-14 2.843632e-07
# subdivisions 1           1            1           
# message      "OK"        "OK"         "OK"        
# call         Expression  Expression   Expression
```

Note that `Vectorize(...)` basically wraps the function (`integrate(...)` in this case)  in a call to `mapply(...)`, so this is the same thing as @baptiste suggested.